# Fragment Orientation managing

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, orientation

The `Fragment` retain state is making me uncomfortable. I don't know where I made the mistake. Kindly help me guys.

```
public class FragmentNotification extends Fragment implements OnAruguments {

    public static final String LIST_ITEMS = "list_items";
    public static final String TEMP_ITEMS = "temp_items";

    List<DBNotifications> notificationModels = new ArrayList<>();
    List<DBNotifications> tempModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    NotificationAdapter notificationAdapter;

    void setAdapter() {
        if (notificationAdapter == null) {
            notificationAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(getActivity(),     tempModelList);
          listView.setAdapter(notificationAdapter);
        } else {
            notificationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if (tempModelList.size() > 0) {
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cstmTxtNoItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cstmTxtNoItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            notificationModels = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(LIST_ITEMS);
            tempModelList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(TEMP_ITEMS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification, container, false);
        init();
        createItemsList();

        return view;
    }

    void init() {
        listview= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }

    void createItemsList() {
        new NotificationModelCreation().execute();
    }

    void createNotificationModelList() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE id='" + tempModel.getId() + "' AND code='" + Constants.CODE + "' ORDER BY priority DESC ";
        List<Notifications> notificationsList = Notifications.findWithQuery(Notifications.class, query);
        if (notificationsList != null && notificationsList .size() > 0) {
            notificationModels.addAll(notificationsList );
            tempModelList.addAll(notificationsList );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setAdapter();// I have tried to set adapter onResume. Because, onCreateview will not be called on setRetainInstance =true
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnArguments(Bundle bundle) {}

    class NotificationModelCreation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            createNotificationModelList();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            setAdapter();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(LIST_ITEMS, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) notificationModels);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(TEMP_ITEMS, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) tempModelList);

    }
}
```

When the first time its loaded, it works well. But when configuration is changed, `Adapter` is set, but no view displaying. `ListView` also initialized. Because, I am getting the `Fragment` by tag like this.

```
getSupportManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
```

After getting the `Fragment`, I used following code.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right,
        R.anim.exit_to_left,
        R.anim.enter_from_right,
        R.anim.exit_to_left)
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag)
        .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName())
        .commit();
```

I have managed backstack also. No issues there. The only issue is the view is not visible. Even when the list has items and the `ListView` is also initialized along with the adapter set perfectly.

**Edited :**

I removed the notifiyDataSetChanged().and i set the Adapter Every time. now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in  **Activity** tag of **Manifest** in which you load this fragment

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

it will not affect any data however orientation changes

Happy Codding!!